# Want to write a dictionary into excel... dict values are nested lists..?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, openpyxl

I've a dictionary like:

```
res = {'err_1': [['ta1', 'ta2', 'ta3', 'ta4'],
                 ['tc1', 'tc2', 'tc3', 'tc4'],
                 ['2ta1', '2ta2', '2ta3'],
                 ['2tc1', '2tc2', '2tc3']],
       'err_2': [['2_ta1', '2_ta2', '2_ta3', '2_ta4'],
                 ['2_tc1', '2_tc2', '2_tc3', '2_tc4'],
                 ['2_2ta1', '2_2ta2', '2_2ta3'],
                 ['2_2tc1', '2_2tc2', '2_2tc3']]}
```

want it to write into excel sheet. so expecting final output like below

```
err_1   ta1    tc1     2ta1    2tc1
        ta2    tc2     2ta2    2tc2
        ta3    tc3     2ta3    2tc3
        ta4    tc4      
err_2   2_ta1   2_tc1   2_2ta1  2_2tc1
        2_ta2   2_tc2   2_2ta2  2_2tc2
        2_ta3   2_tc3   2_2ta3  2_2tc3
        2_ta4   2_tc4
```

Tried using Pandas and others also ...

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(res)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1', index_label=cl)
writer.save()
```

The above code is writing whole dict value in single cell.. I need it different cells...
Please help  us... Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2):

You first problem is that you want the matrix (nested lists) in your dict `res` to be written in transposed form. `zip` can be used to transpose the nested list; but there are missing elements in the lists (that is, all lists in the nested list are not of equal length). So we can use `itertools.zip_longest` to fill then missing elements for us

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> res2 = {k: [*zip_longest(*l, fillvalue='')] for k,v in res.items()}
>>> res2
{'err_1': [('ta1', 'tc1', '2ta1', '2tc1'), ('ta2', 'tc2', '2ta2', '2tc2'), ('ta3', 'tc3', '2ta3', '2tc3'), ('ta4', 'tc4', '', '')], 'err_2': [('ta1', 'tc1', '2ta1', '2tc1'), ('ta2', 'tc2', '2ta2', '2tc2'), ('ta3', 'tc3', '2ta3', '2tc3'), ('ta4', 'tc4', '', '')]}
>>>
```

Now you can convert your dict to a `Dataframe`as follows

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> d = {r + str(c): res2[r][c] for r in res2 for c in range(len(res2[r]))}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
>>> df
      0    1     2     3
err_10  ta1  tc1  2ta1  2tc1
err_11  ta2  tc2  2ta2  2tc2
err_12  ta3  tc3  2ta3  2tc3
err_13  ta4  tc4            
err_20  ta1  tc1  2ta1  2tc1
err_21  ta2  tc2  2ta2  2tc2
err_22  ta3  tc3  2ta3  2tc3
err_23  ta4  tc4  
>>>
```

Finally you can write this to an excel file, as you had already mentioned

```
>>> writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
>>> df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1', index_label=False)
>>> writer.save()
```

Comment: Tq... I got the solution using xlwt.. just written logic to loop all values